# Python: Combing two programs that analyze strings

Tags: python

I am trying to combine two programs that analyze strings into one program. The result should look at a parent string and determine if a sub-string has an exact match or a "close" match within the parent string; if it does it returns the location of this match

i.e. parent: abcdefefefef 
sub cde is exact and returns 2
sub efe is exact and returns 4, 6, 8
sub deg is close and returns 3
sub z has no match and returns None

The first program I wrote locates exact matches of a sub-string within a parent string:

```
import string

def subStringMatchExact():
    print "This program will index the locations a given sequence"
    print "occurs within a larger sequence"
    seq = raw_input("Please input a sequence to search within: ")
    sub = raw_input("Please input a sequence to search for: ")
    n = 0
        for i in range(0,len(seq)):
        x = string.find(seq, sub, n, len(seq))
        if x == -1:
            break
        print x
        n = x + 1
```

The second analyzes whether or not there is an close match within a parent string and returns True if there is, and false if there isn't. Again a close match is an exact match or one that differs by only one character.

```
import string

def similarstrings():
    print "This program will determine whether two strings differ"
    print "by more than one character. It will return True when they"
    print "are the same or differ by one character; otherwise it will"
    print "return False"
    str1 = raw_input("Enter first string:")
    str2 = raw_input("Enter second string:")
    x = 0
    for i in range(len(str1)):
        if str1[i] == str2[i]:
            x = x + 1
        else:
            x = x
    if x >= len(str1) - 1:
        print True
    else:
        print False
```

Any suggestions on how to combine the two would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, a quick review of what you've done:

`import string` is unnecessary really. You utilize `string.find`, but you can simply call the find method on your first argument, that is, `seq.find(sub, n, len(seq))`.

In your second method, you have:

```
if str1[i] == str2[i]:
    x = x + 1
else:
    x = x
```

The `else` statement is completely redundant here, you don't need it.

I think we can simplify the logic quite a bit here. I'm going to ignore `raw_input` and take the strings as arguments instead, but it doesn't change the logic (and is arguably better style anyway). Note that this is not fantastically optimized, it can definitely be made faster:

```
def similar_strings(s1, s2):
    '''Fuzzy matches s1 with s2, where fuzzy match is defined as
    either all of s2 being contained somewhere within s1, or
    a difference of only one character. Note if len(s2) == 1, then
    the character represented by s2 must be found within s1 for a match
    to occur.

    Returns a list with the starting indices of all matches.

    '''
    block_size = len(s2)
    match = []
    for j in range(0, len(s1) - block_size):
        diff = [ord(i) - ord(j) for (i, j) in zip(s1[j:+block_size],s2)]
        if diff.count(0) and diff.count(0) >= (block_size - 1):
            match.append(j)
    if not match:
        return None
    return match
```

How does this work? Well, it basically creates a "window" of size `len(s2)` which shifts along the original string (`s1`). Within this window, we take a slice of our original string (`s1[j:j+block_size]`) which is of length `len(s2)`. `zip` creates a list of tuples, so, for example, `zip(['a','b','c'], ['x','y','z'])` will give us back `[(a, x), (b, y), (c, z)`].

Then, we make a difference of all the characters from our `s2` sized block of `s1` and our actual `s2` - `ord` gives us the (integer) value of a character. So the rather tricky line `diff = [ord(i) - ord(j) for (i, j) in zip(s1[j:+block_size],s2)]` will give us a list of size `len(s2)` which has all the differences between characters. As an example, with `s1` being `abcdefefefef` and `s2` being `cde`, our first run through will give us the slice `abc` to compare with `cde` - which gives us `[-2, -2, -2]` since all characters are a distance of 2 apart.

So, given `diff`, we want to see how many 0's it has, as two characters will be the same when their `ord` difference is 0. However, we need to make sure there is at least 1 character the same in our block (if you simply pass in `z`, or any string length 1, diff will always have length 1, and `block_size - 1` will be 0. Hence `diff.count(0) >= 0` will always be `True`, which is not what we want). Thus `diff.count(0)` will only be true if it is greater than 0, which protects us from this. When that's true, look at the block size, make sure it is at least `len(s2) - 1`, and if so, add that index to `match`.

Hopefully this gives you an idea of how you'd do this, and I hope the explanation is detailed enough to make sense of some python constructs you may not have seen before.